# Asking for authentication informationon Ubuntu 12.04 with XAMPP

Tags: ftp, xampp, wordpress

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with XAMPP.

In Ubuntu I'm using XAMPP as localhost. I'm using wordpress, but when I'm installing a new theme or plugin it is asking me for authentication information like ftp-hostname and ftp-username and ftp-password and ftp or ftp(ssl).

I entered localhost as ftp-hostname, but what do I need to enter in as ftp-username and ftp-password, because without this authentication information I can't install a new theme or plugin in wordpress.

Comment: Please be more precise in your question. I am a webdeveloper and possibly be of help, but I simply do not understand your question. How and where are you installing or uploading plugins? What have this to do with ftp? What is "it" that asks you for ftp credentials? Your Browser? Wordpress? FTP Client (for what?)?

Answer (score 0):

Configure the ftp server in your Ubuntu

apt-get install vsftpd

use your user name and password to login from some client such as filezilla before that you need to configure the vsftpd

Comment: Enable the line 26 by uncomment local_enable=YES